# How to dynamically load markdown files into vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, markdown, vite

I would like to load markdown files like this.

```js
<template>
  <HelloWorld />
</template>

<script setup>
import HelloWorld from './README.md'
</script>
```

I tried to do it with `vite-plugin-md`.

```js
// vite.config.js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import markdown from 'vite-plugin-md'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue({
      include: [/\.vue$/, /\.md$/], // <-- here
    }),
    markdown(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
})
```

But I got this bug when I run `npm run dev`:

```
error when starting dev server:
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined

    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:400:5)
    at exportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:361:10)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:641:13)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:538:36)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:607:31)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1025:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:885:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
```

Comment: It's not obvious from the plugin's documentation it's working with `<script setup>` (although it should). Remember `<script setup>` is a macro, so any particularity has to be coded in it before it starts working. That said, have you tried using it with normal `<script>`, as in the docs? If that works, open an issue about it not working in `<script setup>` on the plugin's repo. It's highly unlikely you'll get help from anyone other than the plugin author.

Comment: I haven't written in any vue file yet. Vite configuration is what fails when I start vite.

Comment: Consider providing a *runnable* [mcve]. Use codesandbox or similar.

Comment: Actually, I tried your shared code here because it seemed good. **It works perfectly: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-d5rotp?file=vite.config.js,app.js,App.vue,README.md&terminal=dev).** The "ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED" always indicates a missing imported package. Perhaps you did not install something or it was installed incorrectly? Please delete the `node_modules` folder and run the `npm run install` command again.

Comment: Always try to check the code incrementally to identify the error. In your question, **you should also provide a reproducible example to help pinpoint the issue**, as I did just now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @rozsazoltan ! I used a wrong package, `vite-plugin-md`. The right one is `vite-plugin-vue-markdown`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I tried your shared code here because it seemed good. It works perfectly: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-d5rotp?file=vite.config.js,app.js,App.vue,README.md&terminal=dev).

```bash
error when starting dev server:
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined
```

**The `ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED` always indicates a missing imported package.** Perhaps you did not install something or it was installed incorrectly?

**Please delete the `node_modules` folder and run the `npm run install` command again.**

Comment: Thanks a lot, @rozsazoltan ! I used a wrong package, `vite-plugin-md`. The right one is `vite-plugin-vue-markdown`.